# How to constrain proportions with the image resize filter

Tags: 6, media

For our *Drupal 6* site, we are currently using the *image-resize-filter* to to let our editors resize our images. The only issue I have with this filter is that when they use the resize handles rather than an image manager the proportions of the image aren't maintained.

*Is there any way to enforce constrained proportions on images resized with the image resize filter's resize handles?*